# Exception while converting DateTime in C#

Tags: c#

I do have a requirement where i need to divide DateTime column as Date and Time column. So when i'm trying to convert the DateTime, it's giving me error stating

> "ArgumentOutofRangeException was unhandled"

on line

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[txtColumnName.Text.Replace(" ", "")].Value = Time.ToString("HH:mm:ss");.
```

Below is my completed code:

```
private void btnSplit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgvcdate = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    dgvcdate.Name = cmbColumnCombo.Text;
    dgvcdate.HeaderText = cmbColumnCombo.Text;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvcdate);

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgvctime = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    dgvctime.Name = txtColumnName.Text.Replace(" ", "");
    dgvctime.HeaderText = txtColumnName.Text;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvctime);

    for (int RowCount = 1; RowCount <= strfile.Length - 1; RowCount++)
    {
        if (strfile[RowCount].ToString() != "")
        {
            if (RowCount != 0)
            {
                string[] column = strfile[RowCount].Split('þ');
                for (int i = 1; i < column.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    if ((cmbColumnCombo.SelectedIndex == ((i - 1) / 2)))
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

                        if (column[i].ToString() != "\u0014")
                        {
                            DateTime Time = Convert.ToDateTime(column[i]);
                   //         DateTime Time = (DateTime)column[i]; 
                     dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[txtColumnName.Text.Replace(" ", "")].Value = Time.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                         dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value = Time.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                            //dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount - 1].Cells[cmbColumn1.Text].Value += column[i].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: debug and find value of column[i] for which error occurs. The problem is because of the value.

Comment: Did you debug your code and see you _really_ have `Rows[i]` and/or `Cells[txtColumnName.Text.Replace(" ", "")]`? This exception seems as does not about `DateTime` conversation.

Comment: You've got a huge statement performing *lots* of operations in one line... as part of a large but incomplete piece of code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yeah wile i'm debugging it's taking the values but showcasing the error particularly on the line i mentioned earlier.
Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: Please post the value for which error occurs.

Comment: þControl NumberþþSent DateþþAuthorþþSubjectþþCustodianþþSent BCCþþSent CCþþSent ToþþMD5 HashþþFull Folder PathþþGroup IdentifierþþFile TypeþþExtracted TextþþFILE_PATHþ

þAS000001þþ5/4/2009 3:45 PMþþasieja@kcura.comþþkCura RelativityþþSieja, Andrewþþþþþþnrobertson@kcura.comþþDEMO000001þþþþDEMO000001þþE-mailþþ.\VOL01\TEXT\TEXT001\AS000001.

The above mentioned two lines are the header and values of the file i'm reading into grid.

Comment: @Aditya you should rather put your updates in the question

Comment: are you sure you are trying to convert value from appropriate column? I guess it depends on `cmbColumnCombo.SelectedIndex` value? also does culture set in your system have the same datetime format?

Comment: Just replace `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[txtColumnName.Text.Replace(" ", "")].Value = Time.ToString("HH:mm:ss");` with `var stringTime = Time.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[txtColumnName.Text.Replace(" ", "")].Value = stringTime;` and if the error still occurs on the first statement, please update your question, otherwise delete it, since it has nothing to do with DateTime conversion.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the code you provided but it's still giving the same error.

Comment: Actually, while debugging i observed that 
CODE:

DateTime Time = Convert.ToDateTime(column[i]);
                  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[txtColumnName.Text.Replace(" ", "")].Value = Time.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

Initially Time is taking Date = {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM} value and later on it's reading the dates in file.